# scaled QIcon in child thread

Tags: qt, qimage, qpixmap, qicon

I need to load big amount of imgs into QIcons (all work is ruled with a child thread).
if I write: `QIcon(filename)` - it'll load all file. and after 150 or 200 files have been loaded, there is no free RAM.
at first I tried to use QImage and scale it: `QImage(fileName).scaled(QSize(w, h))` - it allows to safe a lot of memory. but the problem is to put QImage into QIcon without QPixmap, 'cause QPixmap cannot be used outside the main thread (sometimes can be used, but it's unsafe).

PS
I try to test my application on two "platforms" simultaneously - MS VS 2005 + QT 4.8.2 and QT creator 2.7 + QT 5.0.2
the point is QPixmap "works" good in child thread in Qt5+creator. but in MS VS + Qt4.8 images aren't showed if QPixmap is used in child thread.

Comment: Could you do the scaling on the main thread? If the issue is UI responsiveness, you could call "processEvents" somewhere in your cycle of loading images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the work between the worker and GUI threads.

1. In a worker `QObject`, in a slot (say `loadIcons()`) you prepare scaled `QImage`s and then emit a signal with a signature like `imageReady(const QImage & image, const QString & name)`. When you finished loading the last icon, you emit `loadingDone()`.
2. In an object that lives in the GUI thread, you have a slot that takes this image and name, creates an icon from it, and inserts it into say a `QMap` indexed by name. The type and use of indices is up to you.

When you connect the `imageReady` signal to a slot in an object that's in the GUI thread, the connection will be queued, and things should behave reasonably:

```
QThread * thread = new QThread;
Worker * worker = new Worker; // worker object
worker->moveToThread(thread);
connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(loadIcons());
connect(worker, SIGNAL(loadingDone()), thread, SLOT(quit());
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater());
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater());
connect(worker, SIGNAL(imageReady(QImage,QString)), guiObject, SLOT(makeIcon(QImage,QString)));
thread->start();
```